# Liquibase Spring error: Could not instantiate bean class [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]

Tags: mysql, spring, liquibase

I'm trying to run liquibase changeLog using Spring, as described in [docs](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/spring.html), but i get the following error:

> Could not instantiate bean class [liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase]:Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError*

This is my applicationContext.xml:

```
<bean id="dataSourceLb" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/qacube" />
    <property name="user" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
    <!-- c3po -->
    <property name="initialPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="autoCommitOnClose" value="false" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="10" />
    <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin" value="true" />
    <property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
</bean>        
<bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase" depends-on="dataSourceLb">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceLb" />
    <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:mastertest.xml" />
</bean>
```

and i added this dependency to pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

mastertest.xml is valid, it runs with maven, but i want to make it run with Spring bean.

What is the problem with this configuration?

Comment: is this:classpath:mastertest.xml really the link to mastertest.xml? So mastertest is in ProjectHome? Not in ProjectHome/src/main/resources/ ?

Comment: @Starbax mastertest.xml is in the ProjectHome/src/main/resources/ folder

Comment: Then the property changelogs value should be "classpath:src/main/resources/mastertest.xml". At least this is the path in my spring.xml

Comment: Could you post more of the exception?

Comment: mastertest.xml was actually in the ProjectHome/src/main/resources/liquibase folder. I changed changeLog property's value to "classpath:liquibase/mastertest.xml" and it is working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed changeLog property's value to "classpath:liquibase/mastertest.xml" because mastertest.xml is in the ProjectHome/src/main/resources/liquibase folder, and it is working now.